# Not using initializeApp for firebase with webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

currently my app does not use the firebase `initialiseApp` in the config, as it gets its config from `<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>`.

Now, I am wanting to start using webpack, and so I will not be using that script anymore. However, I use multiple firebase enviroments for my app, and so this `init.js` is very useful, as I do not have to hard code the config inside a js file.

Is there any alternative from the provided `init.js` for module bundlers?

Comment: You can still load init.js dynamically from JavaScript running in the browser.

Comment: @DougStevenson and I can use `import 'firebase'` with that as well?

Comment: @DougStevenson I cant use the init.js when importing firebase.

Comment: Why can't you use `init.js`? What happens when you try?

Comment: You can dynamically add the script tag for init.js to your HTML, and it will be loaded and run.

Comment: @DougStevenson that does not work, I get `Firebase SDK not detected` when importing firebase with module bundlers.

Comment: It does work - I've done it before.

Comment: @DougStevenson huh thats weird - would it be possible for you to share some code for it? I guess I'm doing somthing wrong, thanks :)

Comment: @DougStevenson are there any samples I can take a look at?

Comment: @DougStevenson could you please tell me how you did it? I can't seem to be able to...